# Minecraft Unbalanced square brackets

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

```
{
     Profession:1,
     Offers:{
         Recipes:[
                  {
                   buy:{id:emeralds,Count:30},
                   sell:{id:enchanted_book,tag:{
                         StoredEnchantments:[{id:70,Count:1}]
                                                }
                        }
                  ]
            }
}
```

so i have this villager i want to spawn and i have unbalanced square brackets [] but there's four brackets and I've used json editors and formats and all this. Where is the unbalance brackets?!? I'm going crazy

Comment: Can you add the *whole* command? You've clearly cut off the front, which, while not part of the problem, is still relevant

Comment: Tipp: add linebreaks, so you can read and debug those things properly without counting every bracket twice. As far as I can see you need to add another `}`

Comment: the front was just /summon Villager ~ ~ ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close a `{ }`tag within `Recipes`.
Also it is way easier to debug code when you use line breaks and put bracket pairs on the same tab level (below each others). This way you can easily identify missing brackets.

```
{
  Profession:1,
  Offers:{
     Recipes:[
               {
                 buy:{id:emeralds,Count:30},
                 sell:{id:enchanted_book,tag:{
                    StoredEnchantments:[{id:70,Count:1}]
                                             }
                      }
                }  <--- you forgot this one here
             ]
        }
}
```